# Returning object from suspend function exception

Tags: android, deferred, kotlin-coroutines

Android project:

snippet:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import okhttp3.MediaType
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Response
class DefaultTransportService {
    companion object {
        private val SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = "{\n" +
                "  \"code\": -1,\n" + // 503
                "  \"message\": \"Service unavailable\"\n" +
                "}"
        private val TAG = DefaultTransportService::class.java.name

        suspend fun executeOperation(operation: Deferred<Response<*>>): Any = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                operation.await()
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                val resultResponse = Response.error<Any>(-1, ResponseBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                        SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
                ))
                return resultResponse
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In line

```
return resultResponse
```

I get compile error:

```
'return' is not allowed here
```

But I need to change response when `operation.await()` throw any exception.

Comment: Just remove `return`, you don't need to use it inside a lambda

Answer (score 1):

IMHO In your case I would make your suspend function returning a `sealed class`, something like:

```kotlin
suspend fun doSomething(): Response =
        suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
            try {
                // make some work here
                cont.resume(Response.Success())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                val error = "Service unavailable"
                cont.resume(Response.Error(error))
                Log.e(TAG, e.message)
            }
        }

sealed class Response {
    class Success : Response()
    class Error(val message: String?) : Response()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - Create Sealed Class.
Return a sealed class, something like I already mentioned but that accepts T
type to return the result.

```
sealed class Result<out T> {

    data class Success<out T>(val result: T): Result<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val exception: Exception) : Result<T>()

}
```

2- Use

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) 

    val result = fetch()
    
    when (result) {
        
        is Result.Success -> {
          val obj = result.result
        }

        is Result.Failure -> {
           Log.e(TAG, result.exception)
        }

    }

}


fun fetch(): Result<Object> {
    
    try { 
        return Result.Success(obj)
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        return Result.Failure(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sealed class is more explicit but technically you don't need one as you can make use of `resumeWithException` to propagate the exception.

Example:

```
suspend fun update() : Any = suspendCancellableCoroutine{ cont ->
    launch {
        try {
            // Some suspend functions that could throw exceptions
            val response = getData()
            parseData(response)
            cont.resume(Unit)
        }catch (e : Exception){
            cont.resumeWithException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
try {
    network.update()
}catch (e: Exception) {
    // Handle your exceptions as usual
    when (e){
        is ParseException -> emit(Status.PARSING_ERROR)
        is NetworkException -> emit(Status.NETWORK_UNAVAILABLE
        // etc...
}
```